# Matching exclamation mark in a string in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a line " !".
White space and !.
Two character string.
How can i match this line with java pattern match.
I tried

```
"^\\s{1}[^\\s]+!"
```

but not working.

Comment: Simply this should work for you "\s!". you can use the [link to build regex](http://regexr.com/) expressions

Comment: "^\s{1}[^\s]+!" would require at least 3 chars to match: Exactly 1 whitespace, at least 1 non-whitespace AND "!".

Comment: Remove the tag design-patterns, it is not related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following pattern.

```
^\s!
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this regex: `\s!`
You simply need to match two chars: space(`\s`) and exclamation mark(`!`). 
In your variant you searching for three or more chars`^\\s{1}`(**1**) `[^\\s]`(**2**) `+!`(**3**) - whitespace,  one or more non-whitespace and exclamation mark. You don't need to set {1} for one char.
You can use this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) in order to learn more about java patterns.

Comment: He can _try_ any regex :D Nobody seems to care explaining to him why _his_ regex **doesn't** work.